# Apache Spark: workers are connected and free, but do not accept tasks

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a simple Spark cluster - one master, and one slave. Worker is free and has no busy resources.

[Web UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Mio.png)

But when I try execute any application (e.g. 'sc.parallelize(1 to 10).foreach(println)' in spark-shell) I see the following error:

```
WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

However when application is launched at the same server as the slave, it runs successfully. Looks like somethings listens a wrong network interface.

The configuration is default, cloned with spark from [github](https://github.com/apache/spark).

I start master the following way:

```
192.168.111.204@spark > ./sbin/start-master.sh -h 192.168.111.204
```

slave:

```
192.168.111.230@spark > ./sbin/start-slave.sh  spark://192.168.111.204:7077 -h 192.168.111.230
```

application:

```
192.168.111.229@spark > ./bin/spark-shell --master spark://192.168.111.204:7077
```

What should I check?

UPD: just tried the same with two virtual machines. Works fine. Maybe servers have some problems with hostnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to everyone, problem is solved. As I guessed before, networking was a cause of troubles.

When spark-shell and spark-submit start, they open a port to listen. However, I didn't find a flag to specify a host for this purpose. So, they started listening on the outer inteface, the port on which was blocked by a firewall. I had to add the following lines to ***conf/spark-env.sh***:

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=192.168.111.229
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try:

maybe for some reason the slaves do not have any core allocated, try starting the slave with `-c`.

```
-c CORES, --cores CORES Total CPU cores to allow Spark applications 
    to use on the machine (default: all available); only on worker
```

Comment: I've already tried. No result. Anyway, WebUI shows that there are a lot of resources.